# What do bolts in Neal Stephenson's "Anathem" look like?

Tags: anathem

The Fraas of Neal Stephenson's "Anathem" wear a "bolt".

What do they look like? I'm having a hard time visualizing its basic shape.

Is it like a monk robe, or just basically a square of clothing like a roman robe, or like a Panchakacham?

It is said that they can wear in imaginative ways (like Fraa Lio in the episode with the ants.) Sometimes it reads like they have a hood or something on it, and a little rope to maintain everything in place but I'm not sure if the rope is at the neck level or the waist.

I'm not a native English speaker so maybe that word is too unfamiliar for me to be able to precisely visualize it.

Comment: If it helps, one meaning of bolt is just a piece of cloth woven on a loom.

Comment: See meaning 4 here: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bolt

Answer (score 2):

In 2008 the book release received a [official trailer](https://anathem.fandom.com/wiki/Anathem_Trailer), directed by Brady Hall.

A bolt can be worn (with a cord) like a monk's habit

[image]

Or wrapped around the waist like a sarong

[image]

Various of the [book covers](https://www.goodreads.com/work/editions/6163095-anathem?page=2) have cruder versions.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I suspect part of the OP's confusion might stem from not being aware of the use of _bolt_ to mean [" a roll of cloth or wallpaper of specified length"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bolt).

Comment: @terdon - I'm also had tempted to add some quotes about how the bolt is a single sheet of meta-material that can be stretched, folded, plaited and tied into a endless variety of clothing styles